# Distribution of the number of iterations to achieve success

Tags: hypothesis-testing, conditional-probability, cumulative-distribution-function, f-distribution, non-central

Let $Z=X+jY$ ($j$ is the imaginary unit), with $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,1)$ and $Y\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

I'm running an algorithm that at every iteration $k$ samples a complex number $z_k$ that follows $Z$ and calculates the statistic:

\begin{equation}
\xi_k = \frac{k\left|\bar{z}\right|^2}{s_z^2}
\end{equation}

with $$\bar{z}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^k z_i}{k}\quad\text{and}\quad s_z^2 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^k \left|z_i-\bar{z}\right|^2}{k-1}$$

I know that $\xi_k \sim F^\prime_{2,2(k-1)}(\lambda)$, a non-central $F$ distribution with $2$ degrees of freedom in the numerator, $2(k-1)$ degrees of freedom in the denominator and non-centrality parameter $\lambda$ related to $\mu$.

The algorithm stops (obtains success) when the null hypothesis $\mu=0$ is rejected with a fixed predefined p-value $\alpha$.

For a given $\mu$ and $\alpha$, what is the distribution of the number of iterations $k$ needed for the algorithm to stop?

Until now, I've obtained a rougth approximation considering that, if the algorithm obtains success in the k-th iteration, it would certainly continue to obtain succes if I do a (k+1)-th iteration, which is quite true for large $\mu$, but not for smaller ones. Considering this, I've found the following approximation for the cumulative distribution of the number of iterations to success:

\begin{equation}
CDF(k) = 1-g_k(h_k^{-1}(1-\alpha))
\end{equation}

where $g_k$ is the cummulative distribution of $F'_{2,2(k-1)}(\lambda)$ and $h_k$ is the cummulative distribution of $F_{2,2(k-1)}$ (the centralized F distribution).

I think the problem would be solved if I discover $P(\xi_k\geq\xi_\text{thresh} |\ \xi_i<\xi_\text{thresh}\ \text{for every iteration}\ i<k)$, where $\xi_\text{thresh}$ is the statistic value that gives the desired p-value, but I have no idea how to calculate this.

Comment: You lost me right at the beginning: how does one "sort" complex numbers?  They have no natural order.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the sentence.